# ClassNotFoundException using JDBC in Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am attempting to connect to a MYOB datafile using JDBC so that I can write a Java program to read some of the contents of that file.

As I am unfamiliar I have been looking at a variety of tutorials and they all fail with the error ClassNotFoundException in the same location leading me to believe I am missing a step that all the tutorials assume it is obvious.

The Error occurs when I try to run the following line (as per the current tutorial I am following:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

The exact error is:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
```

Could someone point me in the right direction I am currently using [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-sample-code.htm) but I am not sure why the `Class` cannot be found.

Comment: Have you added the library to the classpath?

Comment: You'll need to add mysqljdbc jar to your projects' buildpath.

Comment: what are you using for the develpment IDE aur Console?
If you are using Console then add myslq.jar file into lib folder in java bin and if you are using IDE like Eclipse then follow the proper way to add jar file in it

Comment: You should show us how you include jdbc driver library in your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing mysql connector jar file in your class path download  from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.0.html

As the name suggests `ClassNotFoundException` in Java is a subclass of `java.lang.Exception` and Comes when **Java Virtual Machine** tries to load a particular class and **doesn't found the requested class in classpath.**

Another important point about this Exception is that, It is a **checked Exception** and you need to provide explicitly Exception handling while using methods which can possibly throw `ClassNotFoundException` in java either by using try-catch block or by using throws clause.

[Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html)

```
public class ClassNotFoundException
 extends ReflectiveOperationException
```

Thrown when an application tries to load in a class through its string name using:

- The forName method in class Class.
- The findSystemClass method in class ClassLoader .
- The loadClass method in class ClassLoader.

but no definition for the class with the specified name could be found.

Comment: Ok thanks this is not the only problem I've having but has resolved this issue, I figured I was missing a library but wasn't sure how to include one or where to find it, thanks.

Comment: @gRnt : You are welcome. Are there any more problems, post it. Happy to help you.